# Override mocha "it" to support "yield" using "suspend"

Tags: node.js, generator, mocha.js, yield, suspend

While using suspend package to handle async calls in my tests, I'd like to write the specs in a more "DRY" way. For example, the following code

```
it('works like fifo queue', function(done) {
  suspend.run(function*() {
    yield transport.enqueue({a:1});
    yield transport.enqueue({b:1});
    (yield transport.dequeue()).should.eql({a: 1});
    (yield transport.dequeue()).should.eql({b: 1});
  }, done);
});
```

can be simplified to:

```
it('works like fifo queue', function*() {
  yield transport.enqueue({a:1});
  yield transport.enqueue({b:1});
  (yield transport.dequeue()).should.eql({a: 1});
  (yield transport.dequeue()).should.eql({b: 1});
});
```

How can I override the "it" function in mocha to wrap the generator function?

Comment: why can it be simplified to that?

Comment: I'm sure it can. Though I don't know what is the right point to override the "it" function. Something like:

var originalIt = XXX.it;
XXX.it = function(title, gen) { originalIt(title, suspend.run(gen, done); }

Comment: `suspend` itself also returns a function, so you can do `it('...', suspend(function*(){ ... }));`

Comment: @loganfsmyth this won't work. It will cause all tests to succeed as exceptions won't be bubbled out. So you need to pass the done function to suspend and it complicates the code for each test case.

Comment: @IgorS. It will catch the exceptions and then pass them as the first argument to `done`. ```it('should fail', suspend(function * (){
 throw new Error("FAILED");
}));``` failed nicely for me.

Comment: You're right. Tried this and it fails, however assertions with yield don't fail. Here's an example that passes:   
it('works like fifo queue', suspend(function*() {
    yield transport.enqueue({a:1});
    (yield transport.dequeue()).should.eql("WHATEVER");
  }));
That's strange... However it works with my answer below

Comment: On the other hand, it's not strange. The assertion in my example is being run when the promise is resolved and that's where the exception is not passed to the done function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Seems like the it function is global. So this is how I solved it finally

```
// spec_helper.js
var suspend = require('suspend');

// Add suspend support to "it-blocks"
var originalIt = it;                  // remember the original it
it = function(title, test) {          // override the original it by a wrapper

  // If the test is a generator function - run it using suspend
  if (test.constructor.name === 'GeneratorFunction') {
    originalIt(title, function(done) {
      suspend.run(test, done);
    });
  }
  // Otherwise use the original implementation
  else {
    originalIt(title, test);
  }
}
```

Then in the test suite you do:

```
require('spec_helper');

describe("Something", function() {
  it ("Supports generators", function*() {
    // Use yields here for promises
    ...
  });

  it ("is compatible with regular functions", function() {
    // Can't use yields here
    ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the solution by [Igor S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694773/igor-s) and it works.

However, I also found that there are two node modules that claim they can fix this by installing them:

- [co-mocha](https://github.com/blakeembrey/co-mocha)
- [mocha-generators](https://github.com/vdemedes/mocha-generators)

I tried the latter one and it worked too. Perhaps it's easier to install a package than write custom code, although the ideal solution would be for mocha to support this out of the box.